# Best way to not show window if its DataContext class constructor throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, constructor, viewmodel

I have the `Window` with one button, click on button opens `NewWindow`. `NewWindow` is empty (for simplicity) and has `NewWindowViewModel` object as `DataContext`. `NewWindowViewModel` constructor invokes a method (e.g. `ExceptinMethod`) that can optionally thrown an exception. I do not want to show `NewWindow` at all if `ExceptinMethod` throwns an exception, I want to show some `MessageBox` "window cannot be shown bla-bla.." for example.

What is the best approach to achive this?

Window:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="OpenNewWindow">Open new window</Button>
</Grid>

public partial class Window1
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OpenNewWindow(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var window = new NewWindow();
        window.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

NewWindow:

```
public NewWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new NewWindowViewModel();
}
```

NewWindowViewModel:

```
public class NewWindowViewModel
{
    public NewWindowViewModel()
    {
        ExceptinMethod();
    }

    private void ExceptinMethod()
    {
        // in fact optionally!
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your example just Change Your code as follows

```
 private void OpenNewWindow(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         var window = new NewWindow();
         window.ShowDialog();
     }
     catch(Exception)
     {
         MessageBos.Show("Constructor failed");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please recommend to throw and catch a specific exception

Comment: Nice. I like it. I used my own approach and your is better.